# Tab not working after upgrade Wordpress 4.8

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-4.8

the tab below on article page edit stops working after upgrade to **WP 4.8**

[image: Tab]

I get this js error in console:

[image: Error]

Any idea to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this on a wordpress install with version 4.8, and it works fine for me.

Most probably this is caused by a plugin, so I recommend temporarily disabling your plugins until you figure out which one is causing the issue.

Start by disabling the plugin which adds the sidebar visible on the left.

Then contact the plugin developer to see if this is a known issue.